# ¿Cómo puedo corregir "The method showOpenDialog(Component) in the type JFileChooser is not applicable for the arguments" en showOpenDialog(this)?

Tags: java, java-swing

Estoy tratando de crear un chat, y entre otras funcionalidades me gustaría poder seleccionar archivos de mi desktop para incorporar. He empleado JFileChooser, pero resulta que cuando trato de emplear el método showOpenDialog(this), me da error:

*[The method showOpenDialog(Component) in the type JFileChooser is not applicable for the arguments (PrimerPanel.abreficherosPDF)]*

Mi código es este:

```
package ActualizacionChat;

import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Ventana {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        miVentanaCentradaConTexto ventanaCentrada = new miVentanaCentradaConTexto();
        
        ventanaCentrada.setVisible(true);
        
        ventanaCentrada.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // Acabar nuestro método.
        
    }

}

class miVentanaCentradaConTexto extends JFrame{
    
    public miVentanaCentradaConTexto(){ // Creo el constructor.
        
        Toolkit miventanaCentradaConTexto = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        
        Dimension tamañoventanaConTexto=miventanaCentradaConTexto.getScreenSize();
        
        int alturaVentanaConTexto=tamañoventanaConTexto.height;
        
        int anchuraVentanaConTexto=tamañoventanaConTexto.width;
        
        setSize(anchuraVentanaConTexto/2,alturaVentanaConTexto/2);
        
        setLocation(anchuraVentanaConTexto/4,alturaVentanaConTexto/4);
        
        setTitle("VERIFICACIÓN EDAD");
        
        Image miIcono=miventanaCentradaConTexto.getImage("src/graficos/icono.jpg");
        
        setIconImage(miIcono);
        
        PrimerPanel PanelTexto=new PrimerPanel();
        
        add(PanelTexto);
        
    }
    
}

class PrimerPanel extends JPanel{

    public PrimerPanel(){
        
        boton1=new JButton("Activar WebCam");
        
        boton2=new JButton("Importar archivos .pdf");
        
        abrecamara webcam=new abrecamara();
        
        boton1.addActionListener(webcam);
        
        add(boton1);
        
        abreficherosPDF archivosPDF=new abreficherosPDF();
        
        boton2.addActionListener(archivosPDF);
        
        add(boton2);
        
        JLabel lblDNI = new JLabel("PDF DNI");
        
        lblDNI.setLocation(5,250);
        
        add(lblDNI);
                
    }
     
    private class abrecamara implements ActionListener{

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            
            System.out.println("Este botón funciona");
            
        }
    
    }
    private class abreficherosPDF implements ActionListener{

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String Ruta = "";
            
            JFileChooser jFileChooser = new JFileChooser();
            FileNameExtensionFilter filtrado = new FileNameExtensionFilter("PDF","pdf");
            jFileChooser.setFileFilter(filtrado);
            
            int respuesta = jFileChooser.showOpenDialog(this);
            
            if(respuesta == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                Ruta = jFileChooser.getSelectedFile().getPath();
                Image miDNI = new ImageIcon(Ruta).getImage();
                ImageIcon miDNIPDF = new ImageIcon(miDNI.getScaledInstance(lblDNI.getWidth(), lblDNI.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
                lblDNI.setIcon(miDNIPDF);
                
            }
            
        }
        
        
    }
    private JLabel lblDNI;
    private JButton boton1;
    private JButton boton2;
}
```

Por cierto, estoy trabajando en Eclipse IDE para Java.

Comment: Puedes usar `null` en vez de `this` como parámetro sin ningún problema, así el dialogo saldrá generalmente, en el centro de la pantalla al no depender de ningún *frame* o algun componente. **Edit:** en este caso `this` hace referencia a una clase que no es un `Component` cuyo tipo es el que espera el método `showOpenDialog(Component)`, ahi surge el error de tipos incompatibles.

Comment: Ya probé con `null`, pero resulta al elegir el archivo .pdf que quiero, me da el siguiente error:
`Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javax.swing.JLabel.getWidth()" because "this.this$0.lblDNI" is null`

Comment: Error completamente distinto, fíjate en ese código que tienes un campo `private JLabel lblDNI` sin instanciar que estas confundiendo con el que está en el constructor, el listener hace referencia a ese global que está sin instanciar!!, en resumidas cuentas, cambia `JLabel lblDNI=new JLabel();` por `lblDNI=new JLabel();`

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El código *jFileChooser.showOpenDialog(this)* está dentro de la clase *private class abreficherosPDF*, asi que *this* hace referencia a esa clase, que no es un *Component*.

Una forma habitual de obtener un componente en un método *actionPerformed()* es obtenerlo del evento que te pasan en el método *actionPerformed(event)*. Algo como *(Component)event.getSource()* te devuelve el botón que ha provocado el evento. Suele ser suficiente para usarlo como padre de un *JFileChooser*

```
jFileChooser.showOpenDialog((Component)evt.getSource());
```

Saludos.

Comment: Nada más falta balancear los paréntesis en el ejemplo :)

Comment: Jo, muchisimas gracias, lo único, he editado lo que me comentas y a la hora de seleccionar el archivo pdf que quiero que me incorpore en mi JLabel lblDNI, me da el siguiente error **Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Width (0) and height (0) must be non-zero**

Comment: El código es el mismo que el de partida de esta pregunta, con la última modificación previamente aportada por @Chuidiang.

Comment: Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Estás haciendo un ImageIcon con un fichero pdf. Seguramente no funcione, ImageIcon no entiende ficheros pdf. Prueba con un png, gif o jpeg normal para ver si funciona.

Comment: He vuelto a probar con la opcion de archivos .jpg & .png, pero me ha vuelto a dar error, me sigue diciendo que **Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Width (0) and height (0) must be non-zero**.